# TextBox[] order by TabIndex?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have constructed an array of TextBoxes, like so:

```
TextBox[] title = MView.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(d => d.Name.Contains("Title")).ToArray();
```

I was wondering, is it at all possible to order these items by `TabIndex` or by sequence, i.e. the name contains `txtTitle01`, `txtTitle02`, `txtTitle03` etc. so could I order by the `01`, `02`, `03`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `OrderBy` clause to the code.  Something like this:

```
TextBox[] title = MView.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                .Where(d => d.Name.Contains("Title"))
                                .OrderBy(d => d.TabIndex)
                                .ToArray();
```

Or order by `.Name`, or any other property.